# Homebrew NoMethodError: undefined method `prefer_64_bit?' for OS::Mac:Module

Tags: bash, macos, installation, homebrew, macos-mojave

Running a brew install << some local package >>

on mac os mojave 10.14 gives me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prefer_64_bit?' for OS::Mac:Module
```

I have looked through Homebrew's releases / bug fixes, clean installs, brew doctor etc. and can't seem to fix this.

The same script works fine on OSX Sierra and high Sierra, so seems specific to Mojave

According to existing SO question / homebrew's github, this issue was fixed already in Jan

Would be grateful if any one has ideas

https://github.com/GRASS-GIS/homebrew-grass-dev/issues/6

Update: 
Still stuck and haven't made any progress. Any brew experts there?

Comment: Just bumping up, in case it gets viewed by some one with relevant knowledge.

Comment: Apparently this was tagged as an issue in home brew, but at least hasn't made it yet to their mac installs. I ended up avoiding use of prefer_64_bit method from my mac module

Answer (score 2):

Find the Ruby file that this installer is linking to, change `MacOS.prefer_64_bit?` to `Hardware::CPU.is_64_bit?`.

I think Homebrew just links you to a Ruby file on the internet which includes installer information.

For example I needed to install an older version of helm and I was instructed to run

```sh
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0a239f96f616d3d00ab400ff1f6f8ab38c5a0417/Formula/kubernetes-helm.rb
```

That is a Ruby file in the release I want, but in that Ruby file lies the deprecated Ruby method.

Instead find the underlying Ruby file from the source code, copy it and make your own gist, then install from your gist.

```
brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/YOURGITHUBUSERNAME/SHA_HERE/raw/ANOTHER_SHA_HERE/your_brew_install_script.rb
```